# Currying confusing about assignment

Tags: f#

I have following code snippet that use currying:

```
let multiply x y = x * y
let double = multiply 2
let ten = double 5
```

I understand the above code, because I remember this code:

> Currying is converting a single function of n arguments into n
>   functions with a single argument each

And then I encounter the following code:

```
let double2 z = multiply 2 z
double2 5
```

I do not understand this code at all. Why double2 can be a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening in your latter example is really nothing special.

You can basically read it as:

> define a function `double2` with one argument `z`,
>       which is defined as `multiply 2 z`

Some people might refer to this as "currying" or "partial function evaluation" but really all that's happening here is that you're defining a function that uses another function in its function body.

Answer (score 1):

```
let double2 z = multiply 2 z
         // ^ here you define a parameter
```

This turns it into a function.